# How can i attach more than one file with Carrierwave / AngularJs+RoR via Json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, carrierwave

sorry for my english.

For now i can create Task with one picture attached to it, i want more...

I have Rails on back-end and AngularJS on front-end. I create a directive which helps me send image to server via json.

```
app.directive 'uploadImage', ->
return{
  restrict: 'A'
  link:(scope,elem)->
    reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload =(e)->
      scope.iFile = btoa(e.target.result)
      scope.$apply()

    elem.on 'change', ->
      scope.iFile=''
      file = elem[0].files[0]
      scope.iFilesize = file.size
      scope.iFiletype = file.type
      scope.iFilename = file.name
      scope.$apply()
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
}
```

Create task in AngularJS:

```
$scope.createTask =->
  $scope.task.iFile = $scope.iFile
  $scope.task.iname = $scope.iFilename
  $scope.task.itype = $scope.iFiletype
  baseTasks.post($scope.task).then (data)->
    $scope.tasks.unshift($scope.task)
    $scope.go('/tasks')
  ,(error)->
   # some code
```

On the server-side i have a model Task.rb with this settings :

```
require 'file_size_validator' 
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
    validates_presence_of :title
    validates_presence_of :text
    validates_presence_of :price
    mount_uploader :pict, ImageUploader
    validates :pict, 
    :file_size => { 
      :maximum => 0.5.megabytes.to_i 
    } 
end
```

and TasksController, action Create :

```
    def create
    params[:task][:pict] = parse_image_data(params[:iFile]) if params[:iFile]

    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    if @task.save
      clean_tempfile
      render_with_protection @task.to_json, {status: :created, location: @task }
    else
      render_with_protection @task.errors.to_json, {status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

private

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:desc, :text, :price, :title, :ed, :category_id, :pict, :user_id)
end


def parse_image_data(image_data)
  Rails.logger.info 'decoding now'
  decoded_data = Base64.decode64(image_data) 
  # create 'file' understandable by Carrierwave
  @data = StringIO.new(decoded_data)
  @tempfile = Tempfile.new('task-image')
  @tempfile.binmode
  @tempfile.write decoded_data
  @tempfile.rewind

  ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
    :tempfile => @tempfile,
    :content_type => params[:itype],
    :filename => params[:iname]
    )
 end

 def clean_tempfile
    if @tempfile
       @tempfile.close
       @tempfile.unlink
     end
 end
```

Where i decoded image and attach it to model as Carrierwave need.

So please help me with attaching more than one image to my model.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a rough idea of ​​how it works. two or more pictures join into array or hash, then send via json with data, then configure as carrierwave needs and reattached to model at the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to create model Image with polymorphic association.So my models are :

```
require 'file_size_validator' 
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
    validates :picture, 
    :file_size => { 
      :maximum => 0.5.megabytes.to_i 
    } 
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Code for upload images in a view:

```
<input type="file" multiple accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg" upload-image/>
```

Create directive in angularJS with help @Nitin Verma (thank you!)

```
app.directive 'uploadImage', ['Restangular',(Restangular)->
    baseImages = Restangular.all('images')
    return{
    restrict: 'A'
    link: (scope, elem)->
      elem.on 'change', ->
        i = 0
        im =[]
        filD =[]
        while i < elem.length
          x = 0
          while x < elem[i].files.length
            reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = (e)->
              im.push(btoa(e.target.result))
              scope.$apply()
            file = elem[i].files[x]
            scope.files = elem[0].files
            scope.iFile = ""
            filD[x]=[]
            filD[x].push(file.type)
            filD[x].push(file.name)
            scope.$apply()
            reader.readAsBinaryString file
            x++
          i++
        scope.arImages = im
        scope.fileInf = filD
        return
    }
  ]
```

And my $scope.createTask :

```
$scope.createTask =->
  $scope.task.ed = $scope.edIz.name
  $scope.task.category_id = $scope.category_id.id
  $scope.task.user_id = $scope.curr.id
  baseTasks.post($scope.task).then (data)->
    $scope.taskId =data.id
    i = 0
    while i < $scope.arImages.length
      $scope.image ={}
      $scope.image.pict = $scope.arImages[i]
      $scope.image.iname = $scope.fileInf[i][1]
      $scope.image.itype = $scope.fileInf[i][0]
      $scope.image.task_id =$scope.taskId
      console.log($scope.image.task_id)
      imageRes.save( $scope.image )
      i++
    $scope.tasks.unshift($scope.task)
    $scope.go('/tasks')
  ,(error)->
    flash.error = error
```

I had to use $resource, because double save with Restangular is hangs the app without errors. so :

```
app.factory('imageRes', ['$resource', ($resource)->
    return $resource('/images/:id.json', {id: '@id'}, {
      update: {method:'PUT'},
      show: {method:'GET'},
      delete: {method:'DELETE'}

  })])
```

On the server side in ImagesController, action create:

```
def create
    params[:image][:picture] = parse_image_data(params[:pict]) if params[:pict]
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    clean_tempfile
    if @image.save

      # render_with_protection @task.to_json, {status: :created, location: @task }
      render json: @image
    else
      render_with_protection @image.errors.to_json, {status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

Method parse_image_data is the same as in question description.

If anybody knows better way to solve this, please write it !

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through each image in your uploadImage directive like this :

```
reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = (e) ->
  scope.iFile = btoa(e.target.result)
  scope.$apply()

elem.on "change", ->
  i = 0

  while i < elem.length
    x = 0

    while x < elem[i].files.length
      file = elem[i].files[x]
      scope.iFile = ""
      scope.iFilesize = file.size
      scope.iFiletype = file.type
      scope.iFilename = file.name
      scope.$apply()
      reader.readAsBinaryString file
      x++
    i++
  return
```

And in your html you should have multiple true in your file input.

```
<input type='file' ng-mpdel='abc' multiple>
```

Comment: try create another instance of file reader. Remove it from top and add inside change under `while x < elem[i].files.length`

Comment: Okay got error you are calling `$scope.createTask` at the end of all the process . So last image will be created as `$scope.task.iFile = $scope.iFile` hold last image. So you need to call create action inside your loop for files

Comment: If i'll do so i get some different tasks with one image, is not it ?

Comment: No each time you will get different `$scope.iFile` So will get different file object. Better you try first

Comment: Maybe i do smth wrong, my new directive in plunker(script.js)http://plnkr.co/edit/fSWLnWIxpCiWrgZUooZf?p=catalogue. Please see. With new directive the same situation, data saved but only one picture

Comment: I have a rough idea of ​​how it works. two or more pictures join into array or hash, then send via json with data, then configure as carrierwave needs and reattached to model at the server.

Comment: You can also do it in one request like. create array for `$scope.iFile[]` And then append images at the time of read. Then `$scope.task.iFile[] = $scope.iFile[]` via loop similar for contenttype etc. You can then read each individually in controller and save accordingly

Comment: Ok , i push each image into array and send it to the server, but now problem is how to save. For save i use method "parse_image_data" for each item in array, but after that params[:task][:pict] become unpermitted.

Comment: You have to allow nested attribute for picture in your controller. like `picture_attributes: [:id, :image, :_destroy]` please see https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form for this

Comment: they are allowed `def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:desc, :text, :price, :title, :ed, :category_id, :pict, :user_id)
end`

Comment: What is your db structure ? You have pict column in your tasks table or tasks has_many pictures

Comment: i have a column in tasks table

Comment: may be i do it wrong from beginnig? do i need 'has_many pictures'?

Comment: You should have has_many pictures like this. Otherwise your old code is okay

Comment: Code is okay, but not doing as i want =)) I'll try to add Picture model, make polymorphic association has_many..and write result here